# Can TclOO objects be shared/aliases between interpreters?

Tags: tcl

I'm implementing DSL processing. I'm using a safe interpreter to `source` the input file.

As part of the processing, I'm building an object.

something like:

```
set interp [interp create -safe]
interp expose $interp source
interp eval $interp {
    oo::class create Graph { # ...
    }

    # add domain-specific commands here
    proc graph {definition} {
        global graph
        $graph add $definition
    }
    # and so on

    set graph [Graph new]
}
interp eval $interp source $graphFile
```

Is there a mechanism to alias the `$graph` object into the main interpreter?

Comment: The question isn't clear to me. Are you looking for something else than `interp alias {} graphalias $interp [$interp eval {set graph}]`?

Comment: Thanks, that helped. I was missing the fact that `graphalias` is *command* not a *variable* -- in the main interp I need to use `graphalias someMethod` not `$graphalias someMethod`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aliases are commands, not objects. However, for calling (as opposed to modifying definitions or making subclasses, etc.) you can set an alias that points to the object in the other interpreter:

```
oo::class create Example {
    variable count
    method bar {} { return "this is [self] in the method bar, call [incr count]" }
}
Example create foo

interp create xyz
interp alias xyz foo {} foo

xyz eval {
    puts [foo bar]
}
# this is ::foo in the method bar, call 1
```

Individual methods can also go across interpreters (with some limitations) if you `forward` the method call to an alias that crosses the interpreter boundary. This allows for all sorts of shenanigans.

```
oo::class create Example {
    variable count
    method bar {caller} { return "this is $caller in the method bar, call [incr count]" }
}
Example create foo

interp create xyz
interp alias xyz _magic_cmd_ {} foo bar
interp eval xyz {
    oo::class create Example {
        forward bar _magic_cmd_ pqr
    }
    Example create grill
    grill bar
}
# this is pqr in the method bar, call 1
```

Comment: @glenn: Consider using the `namespace delete ::` trick in your safe interp, see [Tclers' Wiki](https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/Empty+interpreter) to remove any unwanted commands ...

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up with:

```
oo::class create Graph { # ...
}
set graph [Graph new]

set interp [interp create -safe]

interp expose $interp source
interp alias $interp graphObj {} $graph

interp eval $interp {
    # add domain-specific commands here
    proc graph {definition} {
        graphObj add $definition
    }
    # and so on
}

interp eval $interp source $graphFile

puts [$graph someMethod]
```